# cocos2d v3 override cleanup

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I have been working in cocos2d for a few years now. After making the switch to v3 I really miss being able to override the `cleanup` function. In my sprites I would typically perform all my cleaning up in a way similar to this:

```
-(void)cleanup {
    // Do other cleanup that is not covered by super.


    // Call super cleanup.
    [super cleanup];
}
```

With v3 it appears that the `cleanup` function is private to `CCNode` and cannot be overridden. The main reason for using this approach was that the function would be called automatically with a simple `removeFromParent` call.

Does anyone have a suggestion how to go about doing something like that in v3 other than writing my `destroy` function and calling it manually?

Comment: i think you just need to #import "CCNode_Private.h"

Comment: It really was that simple.  Thank you @LearnCocos2D!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on the use case.

Normally I just call `[node removeFromParentAndCleanup:YES]`, which is enough for my needs.

If you want direct access to the private `cleanup` method in a subclass of `CCNode` you should just import `CCNode_Private.h` in you header file instead of `CCNode.h`.